# Update matplotlib's colorbar during animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have managed to get matplotlib to update a contour plot using `FuncAnimation`, but I can't get the colorbar to update the contour levels. When I replace the contour plot, the colorbar is unchanged. If I create the colorbar with each frame of the animation, then I get a whole bunch of colorbars.

How can I update the existing colorbar?

Here's an example that plots an elliptical function that changes over time. The range of values is steadily decreasing, so I need to update the colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


class ContourAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count
        self.xs = np.arange(count)
        self.ys = np.arange(count)
        self.x_coords, self.y_coords = np.meshgrid(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.z = np.zeros(self.x_coords.shape)
        self.contour = None
        self.colorbar = None

    def update(self, n):
        t = (n + 1) / 100
        for x in self.xs:
            for y in self.ys:
                self.z[y][x] = ((x - self.count/2) ** 2 +
                                ((y - self.count/2)/t) ** 2)
        if self.contour:
            for artist in self.contour.collections:
                artist.remove()

        self.contour = plt.contourf(self.x_coords, self.y_coords, self.z)
        # Without this conditional, I get many colorbars.
        if self.colorbar is None:
            self.colorbar = plt.colorbar()
        return self.contour,


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fib = ContourAnimation(30)
    plt.title('Contour Animation')
    fib_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                      fib.update,
                                      interval=500)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking closer at the [`colorbar()` function](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html), I found that you can tell it which axes to put the colorbar in. If you pass the default of `None`, it will add a new subplot and use that. To update the colorbar, I record the axes from the colorbar subplot after adding it, and then reuse it next time. Now the colorbar updates nicely.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np


class ContourAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count
        self.xs = np.arange(count)
        self.ys = np.arange(count)
        self.x_coords, self.y_coords = np.meshgrid(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.z = np.zeros(self.x_coords.shape)
        self.contour = None
        self.colorbar_axes = None

    def update(self, n):
        t = (n + 1) / 100
        for x in self.xs:
            for y in self.ys:
                self.z[y][x] = ((x - self.count/2) ** 2 +
                                ((y - self.count/2)/t) ** 2)
        if self.contour:
            for artist in self.contour.collections:
                artist.remove()

        self.contour = plt.contourf(self.x_coords, self.y_coords, self.z)
        self.colorbar = plt.colorbar(cax=self.colorbar_axes)
        _, self.colorbar_axes = plt.gcf().get_axes()
        return self.contour,


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    fib = ContourAnimation(30)
    plt.title('Contour Animation')
    fib_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                      fib.update,
                                      interval=500)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```